# Add CSS3 transitions to jQuery Animate script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below I have a script that loads images in a random order and flies them onto the screen beside each other. You can find the script here:

https://jsfiddle.net/38e126f4/

I would now like to be able to add different random CSS3 transition effects to each image as they fly onto the screen. I tried using the step function to no avail.

```
step: function(now, fx) {
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    switch(num) {
        case(1):
            $(".av_icon_"+index).css("opacity", "0.5");
            break;
        case(2):
            $(".av_icon_"+index).css('-webkit-transform','rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew('+now+'deg) translate(0px)');
            break;
        } 
},
```

When I add this function, it nulls all animations and makes all images transparent with a crazy css transform effect.

What is the best way to add neat transitions to these images?

Comment: `$(".av_icon_"+index).css("opacity", "0.5");` is seting transparency to half, it is not an animation.. This is why you see them transparent

Comment: Yes, that was my attempt at getting something to happen. But it makes all images transparent, not just if num = 1. How would I add an animation in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean do the entire animation in css3?

```js
var av_icons = ["http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111227211832/cjpedia/images/c/c5/503px-Luigiart6.png",
  "http://files.softicons.com/download/game-icons/super-mario-icons-by-sandro-pereira/ico/Mushroom%20-%201UP.ico",
  "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png",
  "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111227211832/cjpedia/images/c/c5/503px-Luigiart6.png",
  "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png",
  "http://files.softicons.com/download/game-icons/super-mario-icons-by-sandro-pereira/ico/Mushroom%20-%201UP.ico",
  "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111227211832/cjpedia/images/c/c5/503px-Luigiart6.png",
  "http://files.softicons.com/download/game-icons/super-mario-icons-by-sandro-pereira/ico/Mushroom%20-%201UP.ico",
  "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png",
  "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111227211832/cjpedia/images/c/c5/503px-Luigiart6.png"
];

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}
shuffle(av_icons);
$.each(av_icons, function(index, value) {
  $(".icon-slider").append("<img src='" + value + "' />");
});
```

```css
.icon-slider img {
  position: relative;
  animation: load 1s normal forwards ease-in-out;
  top: -1000px;
  left: -500px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
.icon-slider img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.icon-slider img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.icon-slider img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.icon-slider img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.icon-slider img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.icon-slider img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.icon-slider img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.icon-slider img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.icon-slider img:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.icon-slider img:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
@keyframes load {
  80% {
    opacity:0.5;
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  90% {
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(.8);
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content icon-slider"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Robert McKee , how would I add a transition like: -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew('+now+'deg) translate(0px);?

Comment: This isn't really how it works. CSS transitions (and jQuery animate() calls) define a start and end point (e.g. "rotate 0deg" to "rotate 359deg" and then automatically animates between them. Your code example is about parameterised animations. You *can* do it that way, but you'll get much smoother and better results using the method @Robert describes.

Comment: You should be able to add a `skew` term to the `@keyframes` directive in the code above to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: @DuncanThacker is correct.  You just need to add the skew into the load keyframe animation.  Change: `transform: rotate(0deg) scale(.8);` to `transform: rotate(0deg) scale(.8) skew(15deg);` and change `transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);` to `transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1) skew(0deg);`. Also please run the CSS through an autoprefixer as well so it targets a wider audience.  Like this one: http://autoprefixer.github.io/